# Are red mites and spider mites, the same thing?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

if so, we need a tag synonym:

[Best practice to prevent aphids and spider mites?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1840/best-practice-to-prevent-aphids-and-spider-mites)

I tagged this [spider-mites](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spider-mites) as per the question, but it was retagged [red-mites](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-mites).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're not the same.

#### [Spider mites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_mite)

> Spider mites are members of the Acari (mite) family Tetranychidae, which includes about 1,200 species. They generally live on the under sides of leaves of plants, where they may spin protective silk webs, and they can cause damage by puncturing the plant cells to feed. Spider mites are known to feed on several hundred species of plant.

#### [Red mites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermanyssus_gallinae)

> Dermanyssus gallinae, also known as red mite, is an ectoparasite of poultry and birds in general. The mites are blood feeders and attack resting birds at night. After feeding, they hide in cracks and crevices away from daylight, where they mate and lay eggs. Under favourable conditions the life cycle of the mite can be completed within seven days, so populations can grow rapidly, causing anaemia in badly affected flocks of poultry.

There are no synonyms in the system for either [spider-mites](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spider-mites) or [red-mites](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-mites). So it is likely that it was tagged incorrectly by mistake (possibly because OP himself refers to it as red mites in his last sentence). While it's true that spider mites look red in colour, they're not the same as red mites.

I've gone ahead and removed [red-mites](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-mites) from the question and added [spider-mites](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spider-mites)

Comment: Thanks. At leat it isn't as complicated as some of the overlapping but not true synonyms that we have

Comment: Do you have examples of the not-true-synonyms?

Comment: Sorry I was having to fill out the short comment. We have some cases where tags overlap and it is tempting to apply a synonym but this would not be true. Examples would be chili & pepper (pepper is a more general term including black pepper/etc), and habanero & scotch-bonnet ( the latter is a type of habenero although some people use the two interchangeably)